# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_OFDM' with custom Python OOT Block

Tags: python, gnuradio

I am using gnuradio to develop custom OFDM blocks using Python. I have used gr_modtool to create my blocks and import them into gnuradio. When I try to run my flow graph using one of my blocks I get the following error

```
Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/<user>/asd.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/asd.py", line 36, in <module>
    import custom_OFDM
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_OFDM'

>>> Done (return code 1)
```

I created and installed my blocks using the Guided tutorial. https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python#3.2.6._Installing_Python_Blocks

My blocks are located in

```
/home/ruan/Documents/Blocks/gr-custom_OFDM
```

I am not sure if it will help but here are the outputs of the build process

```
(base) ruan@ruan-pc:~/Documents/Blocks/gr-custom_OFDM/build$ cmake ../
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Found LOG4CPP: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cpp.so
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'gmp'
--   Found gmp, version 6.2.0
-- Found GMP: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so  
-- Checking for module 'mpir >= 3.0'
--   No package 'mpir' found
-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found MPLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so  
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.71.0", minimum required is "1.71.0") found components: date_time program_options filesystem system regex thread unit_test_framework 
-- Found VOLK: Volk::volk  
-- User set python executable /usr/bin/python3
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.2") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (found suitable exact version "3.8.2") 
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git  
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.17") found components: doxygen missing components: dot
-- No C++ sources... skipping lib/
-- No C++ sources... skipping swig/
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ruan/Documents/Blocks/gr-custom_OFDM/build
```

```
(base) ruan@ruan-pc:~/Documents/Blocks/gr-custom_OFDM/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target pygen_apps_9a6dd
[  0%] Built target pygen_apps_9a6dd
Scanning dependencies of target doxygen_target
[ 33%] Generating documentation with doxygen
warning: Tag 'PERL_PATH' at line 1686 of file '/home/ruan/Documents/Blocks/gr-custom_OFDM/build/docs/doxygen/Doxyfile' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
warning: Tag 'MSCGEN_PATH' at line 1707 of file '/home/ruan/Documents/Blocks/gr-custom_OFDM/build/docs/doxygen/Doxyfile' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
[ 33%] Built target doxygen_target
Scanning dependencies of target pygen_python_fae6d
[ 66%] Generating __init__.pyc, OFDM_Carrier_Insert.pyc
[100%] Generating __init__.pyo, OFDM_Carrier_Insert.pyo
[100%] Built target pygen_python_fae6d
```

```
(base) ruan@ruan-pc:~/Documents/Blocks/gr-custom_OFDM/build$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for ruan: 
[  0%] Built target pygen_apps_9a6dd
[ 33%] Built target doxygen_target
[100%] Built target pygen_python_fae6d
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/custom_OFDM/custom_OFDMConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/custom_OFDM/api.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/index.xsd
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/dir_0282a78033921bd56e4fbf13d265c430.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/combine.xslt
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/dir_f2cd86917185299abf5a1f0679072f3c.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/dir_49e56c817e5e54854c35e136979f97ca.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/group__defs_8dox.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/indexpage.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/main__page_8dox.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/group__block.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/dir_359d2bec989c9a8deeeb9aee335c1c76.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/compound.xsd
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/dir_d44c64559bbebec7f509842c48db8b23.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/api_8h.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/namespacestd.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/xml/index.xml
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/group__block.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/nav_f.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/tab_b.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/tab_h.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/files.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/tabs.css
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/dir_0282a78033921bd56e4fbf13d265c430.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/folderclosed.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/sync_on.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/dir_359d2bec989c9a8deeeb9aee335c1c76.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/open.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/sync_off.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/nav_h.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/tab_a.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/nav_g.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/splitbar.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/modules.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/navtree.css
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/files_dup.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/navtreedata.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/tab_s.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/api_8h.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/navtreeindex0.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/bc_s.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/doxygen.css
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/dir_f2cd86917185299abf5a1f0679072f3c.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/dir_d44c64559bbebec7f509842c48db8b23.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/main__page_8dox.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/globals.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/jquery.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/globals_defs.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/api_8h_source.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/modules.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/dir_49e56c817e5e54854c35e136979f97ca.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/navtree.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/api_8h.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/bdwn.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/doxygen.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/folderopen.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/resize.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/closed.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/group__defs_8dox.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/index.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/dynsections.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-custom_OFDM/html/doc.png
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/custom_OFDM/__init__.py
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/custom_OFDM/OFDM_Carrier_Insert.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/custom_OFDM/__init__.pyc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/custom_OFDM/OFDM_Carrier_Insert.pyc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/custom_OFDM/__init__.pyo
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/custom_OFDM/OFDM_Carrier_Insert.pyo
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/custom_OFDM_OFDM_Carrier_Insert.block.yml
```

Comment: 99.5% it's this FAQ: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#In_my_OOT_Module.2C_I.27m_trying_to_use_a_GNU_Radio_block_or_class_but_get_an_ImportError_.22undefined_symbol.22._What_do_I_do.3F

Comment: anyway, this being a general programming question and not about signal processing, it's off-topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was but a restart fixed it.. It seems that source ~/profile didn't completely set the PYTHONPATH even though echo $PYTHONPATH showed the correct path to my module.

Thank you for your suggestion and sorry that it was off topic.